# Google Sheets - script that maintains hyperlink formatting on import a la importRange?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I currently import a large range of cells (2500 rows, 200 columns) using the basic script below. Around 20 of those columns are hyperlinks whose formatting I would like to retain but currently lose when I fetch them. I'm sure this is because getValues may only be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String. Does anyone know of a workaround here?

```
function  importOnOpen() {
var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').
  getSheetByName('exportSheet').getRange('A1:HZ2500').getValues();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('importSheet').
  getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);}
```

One option is to leverage getFormulas for the specific hyperlink columns, but if possible I would like to avoid pulling formulas into the destination sheet altogether in an effort to keep it zippy. Also doing a separate call for each hyperlink column seems clunky, though I guess I could group them together.

My previous solution was to not use a script at all, and instead use the importRange formula which worked just fine (on the other hand note that the 'query' function suffers the same loss-of-formatting issue). My issue with importRange is two-fold: 1) It fetched the data semi-continuously which hurt my spreadsheet's performance, and 2) due to "Loading..." issues resulting from the size of the call I needed to break the request into 5 discrete requests and group them into an arrayFormula to get it to work consistently - this felt clunky.

Could another possible solution be the setShowHyperlink(showHyperlink) function? No clue how this works, and I haven't seen anybody use it so I doubt it. Just a thought. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setShowHyperlink(Boolean)

Comment: What kind of hyperlinks are these and what formatting is being lost? I recreated a sheet of this size to try to replicate your issue but the hyperlinks are being passed over without issue using your code.

Comment: Great question.

Here are some example formulas that aren't being properly called (that is, only the text is being called, but there is no corresponding link I can click)

a) hyperlink(BM2,ES2) - where BM2 is the URL and ES2 is text that I'm attaching to the base URL... only the text in ES2 is being pulled in
b) hyperlink("https://www.exampleWebsite.com/",DK2) ... only the text in DK2 is being called

Comment: What's interesting is that I do have some columns for which the hyperlink formatting is being retained – these cells have actual URLs in them. But at the same time I also have other cells with actual URLs in them whose hyperlink formatting is NOT being retained. Example: https://imgur.com/a/HaxaswA

But again, no cell containing "hyperlink(x,y)" is retaining any hyperlink formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*To copy from one sheet to another in the same Spreadsheet, you can use the `Range.copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)` method with the `PASTE_NORMAL` Enumerator to copy over both formulae and text. For one Spreadsheet to another, the `Sheet.copyTo()` method can be used.*

#### Within the same Spreadsheet:

As you already deduced, `getValues()` can only be of type Number, Boolean, Date or String, and a formula object does not count as any of these. `getDisplayValues()` also has the same issue in such that it can not take the underlying formula.

Checking out the documentation for `CopyPasteType`s, you can see that using the `PASTE_NORMAL` enumeration pastes `values, formulas, formats and merges`.

**Using this, it is then possible to copy the whole sheet in one go, with just a couple of calls:**

```js
function copyAllTheThings() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<sheet-id>');
    
  var range = ss.getSheetByName('exportSheet')
                .getRange('A1:HZ2500');

  var importTo = ss.getSheetByName('importSheet')
                   .getRange(range.getA1Notation());

  range.copyTo(importTo, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

#### Copying from one Spreadsheet to another:

If you're wanting to import a sheet from one Spreadsheet to another, you can use the `Sheet.copyTo()` method. This will ***copy the entire sheet rather than just a range***, but it can be used so that the data format and formulae from the sheet to be copied are all retained:

```js
function  importOnOpen() {
  var otherSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<spreadsheet-id-to-copy-to>');
  
  var export = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<spreadsheet-id-to-copy-from>')
                             .getSheetByName('exportSheet');
    
  export.copyTo(otherSS);
}
```

#### Feature Request:

Unfortunately if the `copyTo()` methods are too slow due to your sheet size, there's not much you can do with the existing Sheets API and Apps Script functionality.

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for the Sheets API and that you would like to request they implement it. Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services.

The page to file a Feature Request for the Google Sheets API is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917).

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - `Range.copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,CopyPasteType,Boolean))
- [Google Apps Script - Enum `CopyPasteType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type.html)
- [Google Apps Script - `Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Google Apps Script - `Range.getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [Google Apps Script - `Sheet.copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your guidance on this! I truly appreciate it as I've been hung up on this for a while.

I'm hitting an error at the moment: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 30, file "Code")

I think because I'm trying to export the hyperlinks to a new (the active) spreadsheet. Trying to update the code myself but no luck.

I'll be curious to see what exactly is being copied over: the hyperlink formulas, or the hyperlink itself a la importRange. I've been trying to cut down on formulas in my destination sheet to improve performance.

Comment: Which line is line 30 for you? Where is the error being thrown?

Comment: Ufffff my bad. This line: var importTo = ss.getSheetByName('importSheet') -------- It's because the sheet name I input does not exist in the "ss" source spreadsheet. I'm trying to pull data from the source spreadsheet into a different destination spreadsheet that isn't defined explicitly.

Comment: I tried to fix it with the code below but no luck because I got an error on the "range.copyTo" line stating "Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. (line 33, file "Code")" `function copyAllTheThings() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<sheet-id>'); var range = ss.getSheetByName('exportSheet') .getRange('A1:HZ2500'); var importTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('importSheet') .getRange(range.getA1Notation()); range.copyTo(importTo, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false); }`

Comment: Thank you Rafa. Because I have so many formulas in my source spreadsheet (I have many besides hyperlinks), unfortunately the copyTo function doesn't accomplish my goal because it would drastically reduce performance in the destination spreadsheet. I've been looking for a script that does exactly what the importRange function does, and it's increasingly looking like that doesn't exist. importRange calls all values with a single formula, and importantly still retains the formatting of hyperlinks. Seems bizarre to me that it isn't possible but it's not the first time I've encountered this.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately these are the only methods available that do what you're looking for exactly. You can always file a feature request if you would like a method to do this! I've updated my answer with this information

Comment: I would suggest maybe doing something about your sheet size though... if your sheet really does have [over half a million cells](https://www.google.com/search?q=234+*+2500) as `.getRange('A1:HZ2500')` implies, it's not really a surprise that methods run slowly and generally expected for large data sets!

Comment: Yea bummer man. For what it's worth, and this is a testament to Google Sheets, my large spreadsheets (well over 500k cells actually lol) work suprisingly smoothly so long as the number of formulas doesn't get out of hand! Thank you again Rafa!

Comment: Will do! Rafa one last question, not quite related: is there a simple way to filter data via a script? Currently I use the following within a cell:

sort(filter(importNew!A:CC,(importNew!A:A<>"")*(importNew!X:X>5)),24,false)

... I'm happy to open up a new question on stack!

Comment: A new question might be easier as it's not as trivial as it first appears! Unless you want to dynamically generate a filter formula and set it with `.setFormula()`

Comment: Thanks Rafa - appreciate it!